# Sublime Text 3 - Open Files in Browser

Tags: browser, sublime-text

How can I create a Sublime Text keybind to open my Chrome web browser on html files?

On Windows I would write this:

```
{
"cmd": ["C:\Program Files\", "$file"]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with the [View In Browser](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/View%20In%20Browser) package. Once installed the default key-binding would be CTRL + ALT + V.

Note that Firefox is the default browser. To change this to Chrome (in your instance) you would need to do: Settings - User from Preferences > Package Settings > View In Browser. "The browser you wish to use to open files is set in the key named **browser**."

If you don't already know how to *search for and install* packages in Sublime Text, you may want to consider these free (after registering, which is also free) [video tutorials](http://code.tutsplus.com/courses/perfect-workflow-in-sublime-text-2).

Answer (score 0):

Below is what works for Windows users, might be similar with Ubuntu users.
There are two Setting in "Preferences > Package Settings > View In Browser".

- "Settings - Default"
- "Settings - User"

Copy and paste the content in "Settings - Default" to "Settings - User" and change whatever "browser" you want at the bottom of the pasted content!
**e.g.:**

- "browser": "chrome64"